# Как проверить, что класс В наследуется от А? (java)

Tags: java, рефлексия

Когда у нас есть объект типа В и класс А - всё просто:

```
B b;
if (b instanceof A) ...
```

А если у нас нет экземпляра В, а есть только сам класс?

Раньше точно делал, но сейчас найти не могу.
Бегу по рефлексии, и мне нужно определить, является ли field.getType() наследником некоторого класса.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Судя [по этому ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504870/how-to-test-if-one-java-class-extends-another-at-runtime) Нужна функция [isAssignableFrom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class))

```
Super.class.isAssignableFrom(Sub.class)
```

Comment: точно, спасибо!